# Dice Notation in excel, get minimal value

Tags: excel

(

with help from some friend i made this : It takes an expression in standard dice notation and gives the minimal result.

```
Public Function Rollmin(r As Range) As Variant
Application.Volatile
Dim v As String, NewForm As String, deemode As Boolean
Dim dee As String
dice = "d"
glute = False
dicemode = False
    v = r.Value
    NewForm = "="
  For I = 1 To Len(v)
        ch = Mid(v, I, 1)
        If ch = dice Then
            NewForm = NewForm & "*"
            dicemode = True
            glute = True
        Else
            If Not IsNumeric(ch) And dicemode Then
                dicemode = False
                NewForm = NewForm & ""
            End If
            If glute Then
            ch = "1"
            glute = False

            End If
            NewForm = NewForm & ch
        End If
    Next I


    Rollmin = Evaluate(NewForm)
```

End Function

When i feed it with a 1 digit dice (like d4, d6, d8) all is working fine.

If i give it 1d4+4, i get 1*1+4 = 5

Here's my problem, when i give it a d10, d12, d20 or d100 (or any dice with more than 1 digit.) it will only take the first number. Given 1d12+2, it would give 1*12+2. Given 1d14+2 it would give 1*14+2.

I need it to take in account all the digit between the "d" and the next operating sign +, -, /.

I tryed to modify it in many ways but i cannot have it to take all the digits between the d and the next operator, it always take the first one and nothing else and then add the other digits after it.

To be exact, i need to make my function to calculcate the minimal value for any dice expression. Given XdY+Z, it would do X*1+Z, given XdY+2+XdZ it would do X*1+2+X*1.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1 :

By doing this :

```
Public Function Rollmin(r As Range) As Variant
   Application.Volatile
   Dim v As String, NewForm As String, deemode As Boolean
   Dim dee As String
   dice = "d"
   glute = False
   dicemode = False
   v = r.Value
   NewForm = "="
   For I = 1 To Len(v)
   ch = Mid(v, I, 1)
   If ch = dice Then
      NewForm = NewForm & "*"
      dicemode = True
      glute = True
   Else
   If Not IsNumeric(ch) And dicemode Then
      dicemode = False
      NewForm = NewForm & "1+"
   End If
   If glute Then
      ch = "1"
      glute = False
   End If
   If IsNumeric(ch) And Not dicemode Then
      NewForm = NewForm & "+" & ch
   End If
End If
Next I


Rollmin = (NewForm)

End Function
```

It works but the expression have several ++ in it. That soesn't prevent it from working well but i would like to know how to avoid this...

Edit 2 : Nope it doesn't work.

Edit 3 : can the split function have several delimiter?

Edit 4 : this post was reviewed and this comment was added to my attention : "Comment: Removed rpg tag as this question has nothing to do with the RPG language"
Dice notation is only used in RPG (RolePlaying Games) I wasn't reffering to IBM/RPG language.

Comment: 16 views not a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
Public Function Rollmin(byval diceString As String) As Long
     dim splitByPlus as Variant

     'Example 1d14+2+5d13
     'Split string in all addition parts
     splitByPlus = Split(diceString, "+")
     'splitByPlus is now Array(1d14,2,5d13)

     dim i as long
     'Loop through each element of the array and adds the current number
     for i = LBound(splitByPlus) To Ubound(splitByPlus)
         Rollmin = Rollmin + Split(splitByPlus(i), "d")(0)
         'First 1d14 gets split to (1,14) and the first element (1) gets added
         'Second 2 gets split to (2) and the first element (2) gets added
         'Third 5d13 gets split to (5,13) and the first element (5) gets added
     next
     'Rollmin is now 1+2+5
End Function
```

Edit:
    Ok my Solution is not so easy to modify. Use this instead:

```
Public Function Rollmin(byval diceString As String) As Long
    dim i as long
    dim convertedFormula as String
    dim currentCharacter as String

    for i = 1 to Len(diceString)
        currentCharacter = Mid(diceString,i,1)
        if currentCharacter = "d" then
            'Skip d and all following numbers
            while i<Len(diceString) and IsNumeric(Mid(diceString,i+1,1))
                i=i+1
            wend
        else
            convertedFormula = convertedFormula & currentCharacter 
        end if
    next
    Rollmin = Evaluate("=" & convertedFormula)
End Function
```

Comment: it works well. really well. But it is very different from what i did and i don't really understand how yours work.

could you explain a bit about your code?

Comment: it doesn't include the multiplication. I need it to do so.

Comment: can you give an example with multiplication?

Comment: it could be 1d6*2 (1 dice with six faces, x2) which should give 1 (minimum result of a D6) *2 = 2
it could be 1d8+2d6*3 which would give 7 (1x1 + 2x1x3 = 7)
it could be 1d12-2+7+1d4 which would give 1x1-2+7+1x1 = 7

This is "standard dice notation" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice_notation) for RPG.

thx a lot for the addition you made, this is much clearer now.

Comment: i got a "rollmax()" to get the max value, i got a "RollMoy()" that give the average value. both are working fine.

I can't get it to give the min value. what i made doesn't work for that.

I need a way to convert dice notation into an equation in order to get the minimal value, no matter how the expression is presented. (including addition, substraction and possibly division (though division is just a plus. i don't need it) no matter in wich order.)

(the sign for division can be either a ** or a x. i don't mind, i'll comply to what is working ^^)

Comment: ps : i need explaination, i wanna be able to tweak it to my exact needs.

Comment: i'm going to work on it. i'll get back to you if i have more question.

thanks a lot :) !!